# Data From MySQL Database Not Showing In ReportViewer In C# Project

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a c# project in which i am using  the reportviewer control  to display data from a MySQL database.I created a dataset and added columns to it. The issue is that when i load the form, the column headers are shown, but no data is displayed.

Here is some of the code:

```
          DataTable dt=new DataTable();
          dt.TableName="DataTable1";
        _connection.Open();
        sql="select id,name from beneficiaries";
        datadp=new OdbcDataAdapter(sql,_connection);
        datadp.Fill(dt);
        ReportDataSource source=new ReportDataSource("DataTable1",dt);
        reportviewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
        this.reportviewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Nothing is being displayed,just the column headers...i had tried binding the data using :

```
          reportviewer1.DataBind();
```

but that option is not available in VS2010. So what can i do?..thanks.